# Как программно узнать включена ли функция?

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с `Camera2API` и у меня есть `set()` который должен активировать работу `FaceDetection`, она выглядит так

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                                    CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
```

и после того как я устанавливаю ее `FACE_DETECT_MODE` должен быть активен, но мне кажется, что он все равно не включается. как то программно я хочу проверить включен ли он... Есть ли какае то функция которая вернет `true` или `false` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30334319/3212712

Comment: и как эта ссылка соответствует вопросу?

Comment: Вроде там что-то на эту тему.

Comment: )) не там не об этом, сегодня ваш магический шар был не прав))